# paintComponent does not work if its called by the recursive function?

Tags: java, swing, paintcomponent

1. I want to see all the <kbd>Points</kbd> one after another but I see only able to see 1
   point. What shold I change to see all the <kbd>Points</kbd> ?
2. In the `System.out` you can see 10 times "set" and then 2 times
   "paintComponent". what should I change that after each time set is
   called it change the "paintComponente" ?

==================================================================================

```
public class exampe extends JPanel  
{
    int x; 
    int y;

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) 
    {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2.fillOval(x-2,y-2,4,4);
        System.out.println("paintComponent");        
    }

    public void set(int X, int Y)
    {
        x = X;
        y = Y;
        System.out.println("set");
        super.repaint();
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) 
    {   
        int e=1;

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("TEST");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        exampe ex= new exampe();
        JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(ex);
        frame.getContentPane().add(scroll);

        frame.setSize(400, 300);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);

        for(int i=0; i< 10; ++i)
            ex.set(e+i,e+i);         
    }
}
```

Comment: Use [javax.swing.Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html), don't use `Thread.sleep(...)`, that will freeze your GUI and bound to give you such results :(

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: He's already been told **all** of this in a [cross-post](http://www.java-forums.org/awt-swing/58917-paintcomponent-does-not-work-if-its-called-recursive-function.html).

Comment: I had described in my answer, as to why calling `repaint()` you were unable to get your Points on the screen, while iterating over your `List`, since `repaint()` requests are asynchronous in nature, hence if there is already one request for `repaint()` in the queue, so any new request will be discarded by the Swing, hence you see only the last update on your screen, in order to achieve what you want, you have to use `paintImmediately()` instead of `repaint()`.

Answer (score 6):

**SIMPLE EXPLANATION AS TO WHY YOU COULD ONLY SEE THE LAST UPDATE : **

*A quote taken from Filthy Rich Clients by Chet Haase and Romain Guy*

```
It is important to note that repaint requests get “coalesced,” or combined. 
So, for example, if you request a repaint and there is already one on the 
queue that has not yet been serviced, then the second request is ignored 
because your request for a repaint will already be fulﬁlled by the earlier 
request. This behavior is particularly helpful in situations where many
repaint requests are being generated, perhaps by very different situations 
and components, and Swing should avoid processing redundant requests and 
wasting effort.
```

Try your hands on this, and ask what is not clear to you :

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import javax.swing.*;

public class PointsExample
{   
    private CustomPanel contentPane;
    private Timer timer;
    private int x = 1;
    private int y = 1;
    private ActionListener timerAction = new ActionListener()
    {   
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
        {
            contentPane.set(x, y);
            x++;
            y++;
            if (x == 450)
                timer.stop();
        }
    };
    /*
     * This is just JFrame, that we be 
     * using as the Base for our Application.
     * Though here we are calling our
     * JPanel (CustomPanel), whose
     * paintComponent(...) method, we had
     * override.
     */
    private void createAndDisplayGUI()
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Locate Mouse Position");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);

        contentPane = new CustomPanel();
        frame.setContentPane(contentPane);  
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        timer = new Timer(100, timerAction);
        timer.start();
    }

    public static void main(String\u005B\u005D args)
    {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                new PointsExample().createAndDisplayGUI();
            }
        });
    }
}

class CustomPanel extends JComponent
{
    private int x;
    private int y;

    public void set(int a, int b)
    {
        x = a;
        y = b;
        repaint();
    }   

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize()
    {
        return (new Dimension(500, 500));
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    { 
        g.clearRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
        Graphics2D g2 =(Graphics2D) g;
        g2.fillOval(x, y, 4, 4);        
    }
}
```

Here is the code, that will allow you to have a look at your points while iterating inside a for loop, though this approach is highly discouraged, for many cons associated with it. Though try your hands on this instead of calling `repaint()` call [paintImmediately(int ...)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#paintImmediately%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29) or [paintImmediately(Rectangle rect)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#paintImmediately%28java.awt.Rectangle%29)

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import javax.swing.*;

public class PointsExample
{   
    private CustomPanel contentPane;
    private Timer timer;
    private int x = 1;
    private int y = 1;

    /*
     * This is just JFrame, that we be 
     * using as the Base for our Application.
     * Though here we are calling our
     * JPanel (CustomPanel), whose
     * paintComponent(...) method, we had
     * override.
     */
    private void createAndDisplayGUI()
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Locate Mouse Position");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);

        contentPane = new CustomPanel();
        frame.setContentPane(contentPane);  
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);

        for (int i = 0; i < 500; i++)
        {
            contentPane.set(x, y);
            x++;
            y++;
            if (x == 450)
                break;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String\u005B\u005D args)
    {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                new PointsExample().createAndDisplayGUI();
            }
        });
    }
}

class CustomPanel extends JComponent
{
    private int x;
    private int y;

    public void set(int a, int b)
    {
        x = a;
        y = b;
        paintImmediately(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());

    }   

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize()
    {
        return (new Dimension(500, 500));
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    { 
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.fillOval(x, y, 4, 4);         
    }
}
```

Comment: no, i have the last question,
I can put the new value in the actionPerformed but if want to have a 
for(int i=0;i<10;++i)   
set(temp+10*i,temp+10*i);

and see each point

Comment: Wait please give me 15 mins :-)

Comment: @user1359266 You are still stuck at your `for` loop. why don't you understand, you need to give time for GUI to get updated. For loop will process very fast, that's y you were having thread.sleep(), using thread.sleep is not good approach, so we told you to use `swing.timer`, `it is used to do regular gui updation`. now again you want a for!!. you have a much better thing `swing.timer`, in your for loop you give set() a new value everytime, do something similar in `actionPerformed()`. you have temp =0, take i=0. then call this in `actionPerformed` `set(temp+10*i,temp+10*i);
`, and increment i.

Comment: @nIcE cOw can't remember but I think that `paintImmediately(x, y, getWidth(), getHeight());` must be done on EDT, +1

Comment: @mKorbel : You are so right about EDT, so indirectly, that call is on EDT, my main calling `createAndDisplayGUI()` and in that I had this for loop calling `set()`, so it's on EDT :-)

Answer (score 2):

1: first line of `paintComponent()` should be your `super.paintComponent()`

2: why are you calling super.repaint(), make it simply `repaint()`

Your Drow should be like this.

```
public class drow extends JPanel {
 ...........
@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
super.paintComponent(g);
Graphics2D g2 =(Graphics2D) g;

}
public void set_list(LinkedList <point> p){
Points =p;     
repaint();
}
```

try with this.
i hope this is simply a structure, your paintComponent() isn't drawing anything.

**EDIT**

```
public void set_list(LinkedList <point> p){
Points =p;     
System.out.println("set_ist");// 1:First this line will be displayed then..
repaint();//2: Then this is called, which in turn calls your `paintComponent()`
}
```

Now when your `paintComponent()` is called it has

```
system.out.println("paintComponent");
//3: so now this will be displayed.
```

Where is the problem here?

**EDIT- SWING TIMER**

Your code was ok, but the function processing is way faster than GUI updation, thats why you were unable to see the changes in front of you. The way you were doing, of calling thread.sleep() between function calls to slow down it's call, was not a good approach. For any timing thing's in swing, use swing timer, i changed your code for swing timer.

Using Swing Timer:

```
public class exampe extends JPanel implements ActionListener {

    int x;
    int y;
    int temp = 0;

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2.fillOval(x - 2, y - 2, 4, 4);
    }

    public void set(int X, int Y) {

        x = X;
        y = Y;
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("TEST");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        exampe ex = new exampe();
        JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(ex);
        frame.getContentPane().add(scroll);
        frame.setSize(400, 300);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        Timer PointTimer = new Timer(1000, ex);
        PointTimer.setInitialDelay(1000);
        PointTimer.start();
        System.out.println("started");
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

       // set(rand.nextInt(350), rand.nextInt(350));
          set(temp+10,temp+10);
          temp=temp+2;
          repaint();
    }
}
```

Comment: Info is good, but to upvote this I have to wait for 6 hours, as my daily limit is over :(

Comment: It does not change anything.
I make a print in set_list and in paintComponent
I see the print in set_list but not in the paintComponent
whot shoul I do?

Comment: Then we need some more code,as andrew said, post an [SSCCE](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22754/sscce-how-to-provide-examples-for-programming-questions).

Comment: In this code I see set_list but after there is not paintCoponement. Can you tell me why?
<code>
public class drow extends JPanel {
 ...........
@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
super.paintComponent(g);
Graphics2D g2 =(Graphics2D) g;
System.out.println("paintCoponement");
}
public void set_list(LinkedList <point> p){
System.out.println("set_list");
Points =p;     
repaint();
}
</code>

Comment: _Please provide a short but complete example which demonstrates the problem_.

Comment: Yes first _set_list_ will be displayed, and then _paintComponent_ because you are calling `repaint()` after it.

Comment: Yes but a see
set_list....all the system.out of the function only then paintComponent.

Comment: You don't have to edit my post to tell something. Also i don't understand what problem you are facing. `I want to have what you discribe but I got some( more then ones) your 1 and all the system.out from function then at the end of the function I see 3.` Post an [SSCCE-Click here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22754/sscce-how-to-provide-examples-for-programming-questions).

Comment: Sorry, I have shenge my first post. I hope it is more clear. The function set_list is called multiple time but it enters in paintComponent onl  time just after the function is over.

Comment: Provide a short but complete example which demonstrates your problem.

Comment: My first post give a complete example about the problem

Comment: @user1359266 hey check BigEdit in answer.

Comment: Now this present update is wonderful :-) , though you missed one very important thingy, in that - THE EVENT DISPATCH THREAD.

Comment: @nIcEcOw yes..may be i missed it,because am not good at it, i am at a very beginner stage, so could you plz point out what i missed about that EDT.

Comment: Just watch my main method, that `SwingUtilities.invokeLater(...)` or you can use `EventQueue.invokeLater(...)` since Swing is not Thread Safe. So any update to the GUI, must be done on EDT,  `frame.pack()/frame.setVisible()` such calls must always be done on EDT, for more info read this Java Doc [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/)

Comment: ohh yes..you are right, i missed an important thing. thanks. i have a question, as you can see if we call `repaint()` with `super.paintComponent(g)` in the `paintComponent()` method, i get to see only the new, latest point. if i remove it, my previous drawing is not lost. I can have a list of points that will be linked and drawn with `g.drawString()`, but when i again call repaint() it resets the window. Is there anyway by which i can have `super.paintComponent()` and my previous drawing is not lost.

Comment: I Guess, for this particular case, you can use a `List` to store your values and iterate over this List Object inside your `paintComponent(...)` to draw the previous thing along with the new. But if you want a greater insight, do read this Blog [Custom Painting Approaches](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/05/08/custom-painting-approaches/) by @camickr , Some wonderful points shared here, with code examples :-) or else I can send you a good eBook on this Drawing in Swing, if you like

Comment: the code works however I dont see how to paint multiple points by changing the set from the main function

Comment: @user1359266 it is because you are drawing one oval, try to take points in an arraylist as niceCow suggested, and then paint it.

Comment: @user1359266 well this is not at all a good approach, but if you want to see that in your code, try removing `super.paintComponent(g)` from `paintComponent()` method.but i would suggest you to go with `list` of points.

Comment: @nIcEcOw thanks for that link, and ya sure i would love a book, but are you talking about _Filthy rich clients_?

Comment: @nIcEcOw thanks man for that, but i have it. just never opened it..:),because of exams. i will definitely read it during summer holidays. thanks a ton

Comment: You're MOST WELCOME and KEEP SMILING :-)

Comment: if in the main i make
 for(int i=0;i<10;++i)
            ex.set(20*i,10*i);
this change the values of the point but it enters in paintcoponent at the end of the for. what to change for it enters in paintcomponent after each time it calls set ?

Comment: @user1359266 As i earlier said, it actually goes into `paintComponent()` method, but looping through that for is very fast, the GUI updation is not that fast, so you feel it enters `paintComponent` after loop. Why you are again going to the old way, use `swing timer`, do something to change the `X`,`Y` value in `actionPerformed()` method. you need to give time for GUI to get updated.

Comment: how can I change the value in the actionPerformed() if I have the nex values X and Y in main ?

Comment: @user1359266 man just change it, as you do in `main`, remember `actionPerformed()` is called after a small a time interval that you specified, an it will fire anything inside it, so you just need to give it a new single `x`, `y` position, and call `repaint()` after that, so that it gets updated. i have also edited the answer, check that new code.