# Looped drawString not appearing in JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jframe, drawstring

I am trying to create a `JFrame` that displays a string in every even-numbered font size from 4 to 24. To do this I am trying to do a for loop that creates a `drawString` that uses a `Font` that increases in +2 font size everytime. Trying to get the next `drawString` placed just underneath the previous by getting the `getHeight()` of the previous and adding it to the varaible `y`. However the `JFrame` is empty when the program is run.
Where have I gone wrong?

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class JFontSizeDemo extends JFrame {
    int x = 10;
    int y = 40;
    int heightOfFont;
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        super.paint(g);
        for(int size = 4; size <= 24; size += 2) {
            g.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, size));
            g.drawString("Name", x, y);
            heightOfFont = g.getFontMetrics().getHeight();
            y += heightOfFont;
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
            JFontSizeDemo frame = new JFontSizeDemo();
            frame.setSize(300, 300);
            frame.setVisible(true);
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }
}
```

Comment: It works fine for me.What you are using?specifications?

Comment: This [**example**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10352884/1057230), might be able to explain a bit about the TOPIC concern. For this you need [**paintImmediately(...)**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#paintImmediately(int,%20int,%20int,%20int))

Comment: @GagandeepBali have you tried the code?It runs!

Comment: @joeyrohan : Sometimes What ONE can SEE or HEAR is really not the RIGHT THING :-) I guess it will only show the last value, at once, without showing the intermediate string literal values. Yeah it DOES run, though on my side too :-)

Comment: @GagandeepBali For sure it's not a right thing to paint directly on `JFrame` but my point is not about the god/bad stuff."_However the JFrame is empty when the program is run_" .But I do get what OP wants :p

Comment: Had you tried wrapping your Swing Code inside `EventQueue.InvokeLater()` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't paint directly on `JFrame`, which is a top level container. Use `JComponent` or `JPanel`. Override `paintComponent()` for painting rather than `paint()`.

Take a look at [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) tutorial for more details and examples.

Here is an slightly modified example of your code:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class FontSizeDemo {
    private static void createAndShowUI() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JPanel panel = new JPanel() {
            @Override
            protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
                super.paintComponent(g);
                int y = 0;
                for(int size = 4; size <= 24; size += 2) {
                    g.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, size));
                    g.drawString("Name", 0, y);
                    int heightOfFont = g.getFontMetrics().getHeight();
                    y += heightOfFont;
                }
            }

            @Override
            public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
                return new Dimension(300, 300); 
            }
        };

        frame.add(panel);
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.pack();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                createAndShowUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Other than the introduction of `JPanel` for painting, there is a quick tiny fix of `y` coordinate, to ensure text remains in the same place after repaint. There is also `SwingUtilities.invokeLater`. Also, usually there is no need to extend `JFrame` at all.

Comment: +1 for this nice example and actually keeping the Access Specifier as `protected` and not `public` :-)