# Why is JAVA paint() method not working?

Tags: java, jframe, paint

Can anyone explain as to why this code doesn't show me a 20 x 20 white oval?
I've added comments so you dont have to search too much. I think i'm doing something wrong in the paint method. or is it something else?
Here's the code:

```
public class Dodge extends JFrame{      //EXTENDED JFRAME

public Dodge(){
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
                                                     //
    panel.setBackground(Color.BLACK);               //
                                                   //
    add(panel);                                   //
    setTitle("Dodging game");                    //
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);    //  GUI SETUP
    setSize(500, 400);                         //
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);              //
    setResizable(true);                      //

}

public void paint(Graphics g){
    g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    g.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());

    g.setColor(Color.WHITE);                   //THIS METHOD SHOULD GIVE ME AN OVAL
    g.fillOval(5, 5, 20, 20);

    repaint();
}


public static void main(String[] args){             //

    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {    // MAIN THREAD

        @Override                                 //
        public void run() {
            new Dodge().setVisible(true);        //
```

Im a beginner so please be clear as to what's wrong

Also please explain as to how this method causes changes in the program when i haven't even called it?

Comment: Are you calling to the method paint(Graphics g) inside Dodge() ?

Comment: no, but it's still causing changes

Comment: and im following a tutorial. it worked for him. and he didnt call the method either

Comment: Maybe you have to repaint whole JPanel in some way, panel.repaint();

Comment: You're overriding the paint method from `JFrame` (originally from `Component`). It's called by the system to perform a paint. That's how it's getting called.

Comment: it didn't work. i've tried doing alot of thigs to it

Comment: oh that explains it thanks @davmac

Comment: The problem in this code is the call to `repaint ()` from within the `paint` method. Instead override the `paintComponent` of `JComponent/JPanel`, which is actually used to do painting related tasks. A simple example can be cited [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10352884/1057230)

Comment: I like the diagonal comments!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`paint()` method is automatically called when a Component is rendered.

Your oval is not getting displayed because it's hiding behind the tool bar of the Frame or Title bar. (The top one what ever you call it).

Change your fillOval to `g.fillOval(50, 50, 20, 20);` and you will see it.

Also, you should always call `super.paint(g)` if your overriding it.

Also, don't call `repaint()` from your `paint()` method.

Comment: you were right about the  oval being hidden. but super.paint didnt work. paintComponents() did. thanks :D

Comment: @ZeroCipher, You should NOT invoke super.paintComponents(...) and you should NOT override paint(...). Custom painting is done by overriding the `paintComponent(...)` method of a JPanel and then you add the panel the to frame. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) for more information and working examples.